# monolog sending old logs

Tags: symfony, capistrano, monolog, symfony-flex

W have web-app, built with symfony-flex. For deployment, I am using [capistrano](https://capistranorb.com/). For logging critical logs,  I have configured monolog in this way:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            channels: ['!translation']
            excluded_http_codes: [{ 404: ['^/security/login'] }]
            handler: grouped
        grouped:
            type: group
            members: [deduplicated]
        deduplicated:
            type:    deduplication
            handler: swift
        swift:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: '%mailer_user%'
            to_email:   ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com']
            subject:    " %%level_name%% %%level%%"
            level:      info
            formatter:  monolog.formatter.html
            content_type: text/html
```

SwiftMailer configuration:

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

And all works fine except logs after each release. I'm getting old logs which were sent before. Example:

[image: screenshot]

Maybe i have missed something in configuration?

Comment: This might have something to do with swiftmailer's spooler. Can you show us the Swiftmailer config?

Comment: @EmanuelOster i use default one, added to question.

Comment: Did you solve your problem, yet?

Comment: Did you check this is not a mail server issue with both sides of outgoing and incoming servers? Mail servers can queue mails when there is a lot request and this might be both end of mail transaction. Maybe you can test this with simple local smtp server like MailDev https://github.com/djfarrelly/MailDev

Comment: what i always do is removing this line. spool: { type: 'memory' }

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 1):

The MonologBundle configuration for the `deduplication` handler type has additional potential parameters  - including

> `store`: The file/path where the deduplication log should be kept, defaults to %kernel.cache_dir%/monolog_dedup_*

It is re-reading the file that is in the cache directory from before you deployed.

I also deploy my site(s) with Capistrano - but I do **not** share the cache directory between different deploys of my site. My config for shared files is `set :linked_dirs, [fetch(:log_path)]` - only shares the logs to keep updating them in the long term. The cache directory is still in ./var/cache, but it's freshly created on each deployment.